# How to stable sort an array in swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting

I've been using the sort() function but it mixes up the relative order.

This is how my code looks.

```
recipes.sort { $0.skill.value <= $1.skill.value }
```

[Swift API](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/1688499-sort) says that:

> The sorting algorithm is not stable. A nonstable sort may change the
>   relative order of elements that compare equal.

How can I change this so that the relative order stays the same as before?

Comment: I was going to comment that this is referred to as a `stable sort` - but I see you've already quoted documentation that uses this phrase. Since you've encountered the `term of art` that expresses what you're looking for, why are you using different, vaguer phrasing for it? You're looking for a stable sort.

Comment: Sorry changing it.

Comment: Swift doesn't have  a stable sort in the standard library. A quick Google search shows a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29322308/swift-stable-sort with some solutions, a Swift feature request: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-306 and this article: https://airspeedvelocity.net/2016/01/10/writing-a-generic-stable-sort/.

Comment: Note that you should be using a strict inequality: `<`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
let sortedArray = (recipes as NSArray).sortedArray(options: .stable, usingComparator: { (lhs, rhs) -> ComparisonResult in
    let lhs = (lhs as! Recipe)
    let rhs = (rhs as! Recipe)
    if lhs.skill.value == rhs.skill.value {
        return ComparisonResult.orderedSame
    } else if lhs.skill.value < rhs.skill.value {
        return ComparisonResult.orderedAscending
    } else {
        return ComparisonResult.orderedDescending
    }
})
```

Took from here: https://medium.com/@cocotutch/a-swift-sorting-problem-e0ebfc4e46d4

Comment: It's really too bad that we have to revert to Objective-C for this. Why on earth would they choose an unstable sort as the default? Could they really not foresee such problems arising from that?

Call me crazy but I will choose stability over performance any day, at least as the default, let alone only option.

Comment: They just assume that the developers knowing what they are doing. Should be a reasonable assumption... "stability" is a mathematical term here, do not mix up with the other meaning, safety, which does not apply here.

Answer (score 21):

The implementation below just work like the `sorted` method in the standard library, without additional limit.

```
extension RandomAccessCollection {

    /// return a sorted collection
    /// this use a stable sort algorithm
    ///
    /// - Parameter areInIncreasingOrder: return nil when two element are equal
    /// - Returns: the sorted collection
    public func stableSorted(by areInIncreasingOrder: (Element, Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> [Element] {

        let sorted = try enumerated().sorted { (one, another) -> Bool in
            if try areInIncreasingOrder(one.element, another.element) {
                return true
            } else {
                return one.offset < another.offset
            }
        }
        return sorted.map { $0.element }
    }
}
```

A stable sort needs to preserve the original order. So we give every element a weight of order besides its value, the index, then the original sort method will just work, as there will never be 2 equal elements.

Comment: @kelin your two edits don't actually work. Please undo or fix them! Thank you.

Comment: **Warning** There seems to be a bug in the code here (corrected in [Tom's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57921819/2547229) that the stable `offset` order is used whenever `areInIncreasingOrder(one.element, another.element)` is false. It is necessary to resort to the stable offset **if and only if** `!areInIncreasingOrder(one.element, another.element) && !areInIncreasingOrder(another.element, one.element)` – ie, when the elements are "equal" with respect to the ordering `areInIncreasingOrder`. Apologies if I'm missing something and there is no fault – thank you!

Answer (score 16):

I appreciate the elegance of [leavez's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45585365/293215). I adapted it to have the same signature as `Sequence.sorted(by:)`:

```
extension Sequence {
  func stableSorted(
    by areInIncreasingOrder: (Element, Element) throws -> Bool)
    rethrows -> [Element]
  {
    return try enumerated()
      .sorted { a, b -> Bool in
        try areInIncreasingOrder(a.element, b.element) ||
          (a.offset < b.offset && !areInIncreasingOrder(b.element, a.element))
      }
      .map { $0.element }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think there is a bug with @leavez answer that your answer corrects. Their code reverts to the `offset` when `!areInIncreasingOrder`, but it should also check it with the arguments reversed so that stable `offset` is only used when the elements are "equal" with respect to `areInIncreasingOrder`.

Answer (score 2):

**In Swift 5 `sort()` uses stable implementation** and soon it will become officially guaranted to be stable.

From [Swift forums](https://forums.swift.org/t/is-sort-stable-in-swift-5/21297):

> ...
>   On the other hand, the actual implementation calls
>
> ```
> /// Sorts the elements of this buffer according to `areInIncreasingOrder`,
> /// using a stable, adaptive merge sort.
> ///
> /// The adaptive algorithm used is Timsort, modified to perform a straight
> /// merge of the elements using a temporary buffer.
> @inlinable
> public mutating func _stableSortImpl(
>     by areInIncreasingOrder: (Element, Element) throws -> Bool
> ) rethrows { ... }
> ```

And

> If I recall, sort() is currently stable, but it is not yet guaranteed
>   to be stable (meaning, the fact that it is stable is currently an
>   implementation detail, and a future version of Swift could ship an
>   unstable algorithm instead).

Comment: I don't see anything that indicates that it will be guaranteed to be stable any day? In fact your quote says the very opposite with "a future version of Swift could ship an unstable algorithm".

Comment: @numist, read the forum link.

Answer (score 0):

I use this wrapper

```
extension Array where Element: Comparable, Element: AnyObject {
    public func stableSorted() -> [Element] {
        let array = self as NSArray
        let result = array.sortedArray(options: .stable) { (left, right) -> ComparisonResult in
            let left = left as! Element
            let right = right as! Element
            if left < right {
                return ComparisonResult.orderedAscending
            }
            if left > right {
                return ComparisonResult.orderedDescending
            }
            return ComparisonResult.orderedSame
        }
        return result as! [Element]
    }
    public func stableReversed() -> [Element] {
        let array = self as NSArray
        let result = array.sortedArray(options: .stable) { (left, right) -> ComparisonResult in
            let left = left as! Element
            let right = right as! Element
            if left > right {
                return ComparisonResult.orderedAscending
            }
            if left < right {
                return ComparisonResult.orderedDescending
            }
            return ComparisonResult.orderedSame
        }
        return result as! [Element]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate the elegance of [Tom's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50545761/542244). Harking back to my Perl days I've reworked it to use `ComparisonResult`  and the spaceship (`<=>`) operator:

```swift
extension Sequence {
    func sorted(with comparator: (Element, Element) throws -> ComparisonResult) rethrows -> [Element]
    {
        return try enumerated()
            .sorted { (try comparator($0.element, $1.element) || $0.offset <=> $1.offset) == .orderedAscending }
            .map { $0.element }
    }
}

extension Comparable {
    static func <=> (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> ComparisonResult {
        if lhs < rhs { return .orderedAscending }
        if lhs > rhs { return .orderedDescending }
        return .orderedSame
    }
}

extension ComparisonResult {
    static func || (lhs: Self, rhs: @autoclosure () -> Self) -> ComparisonResult {
        if lhs == .orderedSame {
            return rhs()
        }
        return lhs
    }
}
```