# How to sort in swift by a BOOL without changing the original order in main array?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sorting, nsarray

I have one array of models which has 2 properties:

**1. title**  (String)

**2. isSelected** (Bool)

I want to sort them based on the `isSelected` property such that it does relatively to the sequence of source array. For example, if all are FALSE or TRUE then there should be same output after ordering.

But if I use following method, it alters the original sorting after ordering them based on that BOOL property.

```
someArray = array.sort { $0.selected && !$1.selected }
```

What should I do to retain original sequence?

> EDIT 1

Sorting order of `title` does not come in picture. May be server send me 4 objects having title Z,Y,P,A. So if all are false and once I sort, it should be like Z false,Y false, P false, A false.

Comment: Is that your actual code? You should see a compiler warning *“Constant 'someArray' inferred to have type '()', which may be unexpected”*

Comment: I have just placed a prototype

Comment: What you are (apparently) looking for is a “stable” sort. In Swift 5 the `sort()` method happens to be stable, but that is not guaranteed.

Comment: See also [How to stable sort an array in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40673374/how-to-stable-sort-an-array-in-swift).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of sorting, you can do that more effectively using a filter operation:

```
let newArray = array.filter { $0.selected } + array.filter { !$0.selected }
```

Unfortunately, `Array.sorted` does not guarantee a stable sort, therefore you cannot just sort by one property and expect the original sort to be kept.

You can implement stable sort easily though (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50545761/669586)

Then you can simply use:

```
let newArray = array.stableSorted {    
   let numeric1 = $0.selected ? 0 : 1
   let numeric2 = $1.selected ? 0 : 1

   return numeric1 <= numeric2
}
```

or

```
let newArray = array.stableSorted {
   return $0.selected == $1.selected || $0.selected
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You need

```
someArray = array.sorted (by:{ $0.selected && !$1.selected && <#Add more conditions #>})
```

`sorted (by` doesn't mutate original array unlike `sort`

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1688499-sort

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2296815-sorted

Comment: Thanks, see my EDIT

Comment: @RakeshaShastri being || or && is according to the logic the op needs

Comment: @Sh_Khan there is an `if`. if that is also according to the OP needs, you could just have written `array.sorted (by: <# What OP needs #>)`. I don't see any difference.

Comment: Works))) - usersArray.sorted { $0.isVarified && !$1.isVarified }

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `sorted` method instead of `sort`;

```
let newArray = array.sorted { $0.selected && !$1.selected }
```

Basically `sort` sorts in the same array, `sorted` return a new array, without changing the original

Answer (score 2):

If you want to preserve the order that you get from a server I will suggest you not using `sort` or `sorted` method, because they are not guaranteed to preserve original order for keys with the same order. I will recommend you to write own sorting-like function:

```
struct Model {
    let title:String
    let selected:Bool
}

let array = [ Model(title: "Z", selected: true), Model(title: "Z", selected: false), Model(title: "Y", selected: false), Model(title: "P", selected: false), Model(title: "A", selected: true), Model(title: "A", selected: false)]

extension Array where Element == Model {
    func preserveSorted() -> [Model] {
        var selected:[Model] = []
        var notSelected:[Model] = []

        for model in self {
            if model.selected {
                selected.append(model)
            } else {
                notSelected.append(model)
            }
        }
        var output:[Model] = []
        output.append(contentsOf: selected)
        output.append(contentsOf: notSelected)
        return output
    }
}


var newArray:[Model] = array.preserveSorted()
print(newArray)
/* output:
[
    Model(title: "Z", selected: true),
    Model(title: "A", selected: true),
    Model(title: "Z", selected: false),
    Model(title: "Y", selected: false),
    Model(title: "P", selected: false),
    Model(title: "A", selected: false)
]
*/
```

---

If you don't want to create `Comparable` extension to your model (because for example, you are using a different order of these models in a few places), you can use method `sorted`, but provide a different sorting block:

```
struct Model {
    let title:String
    let selected:Bool
}

let array = [ Model(title: "a", selected: true), Model(title: "a", selected: false), Model(title: "b", selected: false), Model(title: "c", selected: true)]

let newArray = array.sorted { (lhs, rhs) -> Bool in
    if lhs.selected == rhs.selected {
        return lhs.title < rhs.title
    }
    return lhs.selected
}
print(newArray)
```

and the sorting order will be:

```
[
  Model(title: "a", selected: true), 
  Model(title: "c", selected: true), 
  Model(title: "a", selected: false), 
  Model(title: "b", selected: false)
 ]
```

Comment: Thanks, title does not come in picture. May be server send me 4 objects having title Z,Y,P,A. So if all are false and once I sort, it should be like Z false,Y false, P false, A false.

Comment: @NSPratik I've updated my answer, could you check it?