# Shuffle struct by Int

Tags: arrays, swift, shuffle

How I can **shuffle** my struct by `variable priority` and display in TableView?

So now I have **20** documents in my struct, but later I will have **100+** documents in my struct.

5 or 7 or 10 documents will have `priority` from 10 to 1, other documents have `priority` 0. Me need display 5 or 7 or 10 documents on top position in tableView. Other documents which have `priority` 0 must be located after firsts 5 or 7 or 10 documents in random order.

I. e. the firsts 5 or 7 or 10 documents should be placed depending on the priority, if a document has `priority` 10, it should be the first one, the next one which has `priority` 9 should be behind the document with `priority` 10 and so on to the document with priority 1. Other documents due be randomly in order.

This code which help me get documents from `firestore`:

```
fileprivate func observeQuery() {
    MBProgressHUD.showAdded(to: self.view, animated: true)
    guard let query = query else { return }
    let time = DispatchTime.now() + 0.5
    listener = query.addSnapshotListener { [unowned self] (snapshot, error) in
        if let snapshot = snapshot {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: time) {
                var photoModels = snapshot.documents.map { (document) -> Photographer in
                    if let photoModel = Photographer(dictionary: document.data(), id: document.documentID) {
                        return photoModel
                    } else {
                        fatalError("Fatal error")
                    }
                }
                self.photographers = photoModels
                // this need use shuffle
                self.document = snapshot.documents
                self.tableView.reloadData()
                MBProgressHUD.hide(for: self.view, animated: true)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Should the documents with a non-zero priority be shuffled too? Or keep their original order? Can many documents have the same priority? for example 3 documents with priority 10?

Comment: @ielyamani Non-zero need shuffle too. No, only one document have priority 10, only one document have priority 9 and etc

Comment: So if you're going to ask about sorting documents in a struct, you need to show the definition of your struct in your question. (Show all the parts of your data model that are relevant to the question.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you could do is

- Sort the documents by decreasing priority first.
- Then shuffle the part of the array with documents with zero priority.

Example:

```
var sorted = documents.sorted(by: { $0.priority > $1.priority } )
if let idx = sorted.firstIndex(where: { $0.priority == 0 }) {
    sorted[idx...].shuffle()
}
```

An alternative is to shuffle the complete array and then do a “stable sort” by decreasing priority, using the ideas from [How to stable sort an array in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40673374/how-to-stable-sort-an-array-in-swift):

```
let sorted = documents.shuffled().enumerated()
    .sorted(by: { ($0.element.priority, $0.offset) > ($1.element.priority, $1.offset) })
    .map { $0.element }
```

This would sort the entries by decreasing order, and randomly shuffle *all* entries with identical priority, not only the entries with zero priority.

*Remark:* The sort methods from the Swift standard library happens to be stable in Swift 5, so that the last approach could be simplified to

```
let sorted = documents.shuffled()
    .sorted(by: { $0.priority > $1.priority } )
```

However, that is not guaranteed, compare [Is sort() stable in Swift 5?](https://forums.swift.org/t/is-sort-stable-in-swift-5/21297) in the Swift forum.

Comment: Nice trick with comparable tuples! I'll have to start using that.

Comment: @Sulthan: I learned that from Hamish at https://stackoverflow.com/a/37612765/1187415.

Comment: partition is faster than sort for binning, since sort is really just a bunch of partitions.  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3017524-partition

Comment: @JoshHomann That's a resourceful idea ! See The benchmarks below. I've included it in my answer if you don't mind

Answer (score 0):

You could put the documents into buckets:

```
var buckets = Array(repeating: [Document](), count: 11)

for i in documents.indices {
    buckets[10 - documents[i].priority].append(documents[i])
}
```

This is an O(*n*) algorithm worst case unlike TimSort's O(*n*log(*n*)).

and then shuffle the last bucket :

```
buckets[10].shuffle()
```

last but not least, `flatMap` the `buckets` array:

```
let sorted = buckets.flatMap { $0 }
```

---

### Speed Shuffle

[image: Muhammad Ali]

If you'd like to an even faster shuffle, you could use this [modified](https://twitter.com/iklil_Elyamani/status/1102934475938426880?s=20) [Fisher-Yates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) Algorithm (Faster than `Array.shuffled()`):

```
extension Array where Element: Comparable {
    mutating func fisherYatesShuffle()  {
        if count < 2 {
            return
        }
        for i in 1..<count {
            let ix = abs(x.next()) % (i+1)
            swapAt(i,ix)
        }
    }
}
```

Or more generally for `MutableCollection` (which would include `ArraySlice`):

```
extension MutableCollection where Index == Int, Element: Comparable {
    mutating func fisherYatesShuffle()  {
        if count < 2 {
            return
        }

        let start = self.index(after: startIndex)

        for i in start..<endIndex {
            let ix = abs(x.next()) % (i + 1 - startIndex) + startIndex
            swapAt(i, ix)
        }
    }
}
```

This extension uses a [Xoshiro random number generator](http://xoshiro.di.unimi.it/) (Faster than `Int.random(in:)`, but less random/uniform):

```
struct Xoshiro: RandomNumberGenerator {
    public typealias StateType = (UInt32, UInt32, UInt32, UInt32)

    private var state: StateType

    public init(seed: StateType) {
        self.state = seed
    }

    public mutating func next() -> Int {
        let x = state.1 &* 5
        let result = ((x &<< 7) | (x &>> 25)) &* 9
        let t = state.1 &<< 9
        state.2 ^= state.0
        state.3 ^= state.1
        state.1 ^= state.2
        state.0 ^= state.3
        state.2 ^= t
        state.3 = (state.3 &<< 21) | (state.3 &>> 11)
        return Int(result)
    }
}

var x = Xoshiro(seed: (UInt32.random(in: 0..<10),  //Other upper limits could be used to increase randomness
                       UInt32.random(in: 0..<10),
                       UInt32.random(in: 0..<10),
                       UInt32.random(in: 0..<10)))
```

To use it, `Document` should be `Comparable` :

```
struct Document: Comparable {
    let priority: Int
    static func < (lhs: Document, rhs: Document) -> Bool {
        return lhs.priority < rhs.priority
    }
}
```

and call our shuffle like so:

```
buckets[10].fisherYatesShuffle()
```

---

### Partition, Sort, Shuffle

As per **Josh Homann**'s suggestion, you could also partition the `documents` array putting the documents with zero priority after a pivot index. Then sort the first partition, and shuffle the second one :

```
var result = documents
let pivot = result.partition { $0.priority == 0 }
result[..<pivot].sort(by: > )
result[pivot...].shuffle()
```

---

### Benchmarks

[Here](https://tio.run/##5VZtb9s2EP6uX3EF0k5cHFlyFhQzEg9tsq4rkLVYOmCD4Q20RMVEJMogqbwsy19fdqQoicpL660bNmD6YkvHe@7uuTeqC57rL25vebmupIZXVS0yqnklgiAYj3c@/OCJI5YWVFoNtYFCoLSsUw0/VmrFZTWF76nIqvK7ulwy@Q0TDKEqCdcB4LOulwVPQV@tGS04VXCiqWbv8RUOIPzhW6F3JyN4@JdYhAZG8nPUg3MqQRmEaQ/knWqMccF1qBjLvEPE@WMexYo8sijogzlnJTf3cMoaz3BxCnktUhDsUocEdmaAznloBdNwaYAMYJTAs89hbyCUTNWFNuGGl/Bsfx@eE/gNzP/ZDCZ7hBiVLwcq2sdDjV7afJ3Az@2B@I5otxcld0RJL5rcEcW9aPchW/qeFQyn/Ws8nCQ2qO4ThpYkpNOSTNdSGObChg7iOL8JApNTQ6CrJ5c5VxuRtMUVcjGFOIr2k5iMOtQ7z7@qQYhptuMq4zlnGbziasUk/IR0KKiVqSIXX4B1xITCZoNjLLBlwQ6romCpaT@4QCWGNGUMGTkwfI3g64KVTOgpHFblGvsUNVz5DQs0tyatxZNVnecFw3L1CpXnkOJo0IDZ8j736ek@YVL8asSkSluRpm@48S2kuWZy2kist6RXybH5OTZhI0V2mMiaiIZGDTQ3iadLFV5GTX8ReAohh21IYMeHxy/92wBGXdD1Cx3yEYIRL4Suvsbjt5KfckGLQVa8PLyQkl457v86262VIeunNZWZIx57Alih2MfYv8dkgiw2EI9Q6OqRPA35ttd2A34eocdN86MqrR8J3FjBAVxJrq@mpiaDdhDgkLRk7ENYrNS0AxmB9F/t1HxZVYXnvpsIqBa12AgjvVc/gx9fYoe4vJpI9IpB5iwroCa3m2w1E6VYSvRZveanq3cSaZ3vjeD5CJJ44TreVUdInjQKmX86NKNgAEGikq7hGn7BJNpwWkbCAZ/@OMFUR2acmLiNhV@ZfGcRWwOTON4ENibtbO25OPD93e6hg6A7E6l2dGxG@0sm0lVJ5dlGN4fx@E1Fz3gJR1Rw7IRKfKbQtldn7aw5wsYKSf8ZLzY4VQ/Ac7T5NFzEOZfKqG/FfVXhHI3hq7s87yRxbEc3gal/fDj5WFoJY3Yr@XN4yX08V/CNhzMH7d08jD1mjXmxt5cfTC3KIs1LhnaZPKfFCRcpCy1fZOQIigqq9BPS9MwxSvinENxUQhb2Y8ORHi6xwK4HJM8GFN0A@WdieoM7FF5XJRWbBGaqv7t9dYH1M42fV0bSHInWhi@7ha/v10@To@bkHNNsdReWD8vGzEXsTlgxdvLC66dPJ8Q56hPy8GrbhJhlnZ4xOxTs@sN7GV7RzX6bwrydJ4sQrdrFM@2uc8FgM/XlghcDnuJlp29IZ2GexLjLu4Nzvui4XUR0vcaYQ19KvKboIRbRhzZu79mgmJ16lBdUH9uRuRX7F/2/vT7fr/j/hv3/Cuv43N7@nqK1U3W78/YP) are some benchmarks :

```
Joakim Danielson's : 1643µs
MartinR's          :  169µs 
Josh Homann's      :  152µs
Orig. Fisher-Yates :   38µs
This               :   15µs
```

(Even though TIO uses Swift 4, relatively comparable results were got using the same code on my local machine with Swift 5, run in the terminal with optimizations)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution where all elements in the array gets sorted at once

```
array.sort(by: {
    let first = $0.priority == 0 ? Double.random(in: 0..<1) : Double($0.priority)
    let second = $1.priority == 0 ? Double.random(in: 0..<1) : Double($1.priority)
    return first > second
})
```

If you want to avoid the cast to Double you can define a negative range for the random numbers, I just hardcoded a value here but one option could be to base the min value (-1000) on the size of `array`

```
array.sort(by: {
    let first = $0.priority == 0 ? Int.random(in: -1000..<1) : $0.priority
    let second = $1.priority == 0 ? Int.random(in: -1000..<1) : $1.priority
    return first > second
})
```