# Why is Int.random() slower than arc4random_uniform()?

Tags: swift, random

I have used Int.random() method and arc4random_uniform() for number generation speed tests.
Both tests were run in macOS console with build configuration set to release.
Below are codes which I have used for testing.

```
public func randomGen1() {
    let n = 1_000_000
    let startTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
    for i in 0..<n {
        _ = arc4random_uniform(10)
    }
    let timeElapsed = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - startTime
    print(timeElapsed)
}
public func randomGen2() {
    let n = 1_000_000
    let startTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
    for i in 0..<n {
        _ = Int.random(in: 0..<10)
    }
    let timeElapsed = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - startTime
    print(timeElapsed)
}
```

The times I got are 
0.029475092887878418 (for arc4random_uniform(10))
0.20298802852630615  (for Int.random(in: 0..<10))

Why is Int.random() so much slower?
Is there a way to optimise it?
Are there any faster methods for random number generation in swift?

Comment: What optimizer settings were you using?

Comment: Looking at the code in the profiler, it seems that `Int.random(in:)` is using `arc4random_buf` internally which appears to be a lot slower than the `arc4random` that `arc4random_uniform` uses.

Comment: I don't know if that explains it, but from a quick look at https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Random.swift it seems that each call to `next(upperBound:)` computes a 64-bit random number (no matter what the upper bound is), and that calls (as @rmaddy observed) `arc4random_buf` with an 8 byte buffer on Apple platforms.

Comment: Yep. `random(in:)` uses the `SystemRandomNumberGenerator`, which calls `swift_stdlib_random`, which calls `arc4random_buf`.

Comment: To be fair `arc4random_uniform()` produces a `UInt32`, and thus it should be compared to `UInt32.random(in:)`

Comment: @ielyamani: I tried that and it makes no difference. Both Int.random() and UInt32.random() compute a 64-bit random number and then “truncate” the result to the desired range.

Comment: @MartinR In my tests too, I just mentioned that it should be taken into consideration. If implemented properly there should be a difference.

Comment: @Alexander I am using [-Os] optimization level.

Comment: Never use `CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent`: it's a Wall clock, affected by leap seconds in your calendar. Instead, use a monotonic clock: `mach_absolute_time()`, `ProcessInfo.processInfo.systemUptime`, `DispatchTime.now()` or `CACurrentMediaTime()`.

Comment: See the update 

Answer (score 2):

### Update

[This](https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/25286) implementation of a random number generator in an interval has been merged into the standard library and should perform better than before:

```
// s = upperBound; r1, r2 = random numbers from generator
func bounded(s: UInt64, r1:UInt64, r2: UInt64) -> UInt64 {
    // r1 would come from invoking generator's next()
    var m = r1.multipliedFullWidth(by: s)
    if m.low < s {
        // let t = (0 &- s) % s // Lemire's original form
        var t = 0 &- s // O'Neill's modulo optimization
        if t >= s {
            t &-= s
            if t >= s {
                t %= s
            }
        }
        while m.low < t {
            // r2 would come from invoking generator's next()
            m = r2.multipliedFullWidth(by: s)
        }
    }
    return m.high
}
```

See the answer below for more details.

### Answer

An answer to your second question :

> "Are there any faster methods for random number generation in swift?"

I've [previously used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55548872/shuffle-struct-by-int/55549494#55549494) the [**Xoshiro**](http://xoshiro.di.unimi.it/) Pseudo-Random Number Generator which is pretty fast.

Here the code used for benchmarking :

- **randomGen1**

```
import Foundation

public func randomGen1() {
    let n = 1_000_000
    var sum: UInt32 = 0
    let startTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
    for _ in 0..<n {
        sum = sum &+ arc4random_uniform(10)
    }
    let timeElapsed = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - startTime
    print(sum, timeElapsed)
}

do {
    randomGen1()
}
```

- **randomGen2**

```
public func randomGen2() {
    let n = 1_000_000
    var sum: UInt32 = 0
    let startTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
    for _ in 0..<n {
        sum = sum &+ UInt32.random(in: 0..<10)
    }
    let timeElapsed = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - startTime
    print(sum, timeElapsed)
}


do {
    randomGen2()
}
```

- Xoshiro random number generator from [this library](https://github.com/mattgallagher/CwlUtils/blob/e4186dae4ba55ffa478264c8477d01a48fd2b459/Sources/CwlUtils/CwlRandom.swift#L80):

```
struct Xoshiro: RandomNumberGenerator {
    public typealias StateType = (UInt32, UInt32, UInt32, UInt32)

    private var state: StateType

    public init(seed: StateType) {
        self.state = seed
    }

    public mutating func next() -> Int {
        let x = state.1 &* 5
        let result = ((x &<< 7) | (x &>> 25)) &* 9
        let t = state.1 &<< 9
        state.2 ^= state.0
        state.3 ^= state.1
        state.1 ^= state.2
        state.0 ^= state.3
        state.2 ^= t
        state.3 = (state.3 &<< 21) | (state.3 &>> 11)
        return Int(result)
    }
}

var x = Xoshiro(seed: (UInt32.random(in: 0..<10),  //Other upper limits could be used to increase randomness
    UInt32.random(in: 0..<10),
    UInt32.random(in: 0..<10),
    UInt32.random(in: 0..<10)))

public func randomGen3() {
    let n = 1_000_000
    var sum: UInt32 = 0
    let startTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
    for _ in 0..<n {
        sum = sum &+ UInt32(abs(x.next()) % 10)
    }
    let timeElapsed = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - startTime
    print(sum, timeElapsed)
}

do {
    randomGen3()
}
```

Xoshiro is fast but does not pass all randomness tests. If security is of concern then you could use [Wyhash](https://lemire.me/blog/2019/03/19/the-fastest-conventional-random-number-generator-that-can-pass-big-crush/).

[**Daniel Lemire**](https://lemire.me/en/) (the author of [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1805.10941.pdf) paper) has kindly just sent me a [Swift implementation](https://github.com/lemire/SwiftWyhash) of Wyhash:

```
class WyhashGenerator {
    var seed : UInt64

    let multiplier1 : UInt64 = 0xa3b195354a39b70d
    let multiplier2 : UInt64 = 0x1b03738712fad5c9
    let increment : UInt64 = 0x60bee2bee120fc15

    init(userSeed : UInt64) {
        seed = userSeed;
    }

    func random() -> UInt64 {
        seed &+= increment
        let fullmult1 = seed.multipliedFullWidth(by: multiplier1)
        let m1 = fullmult1.high ^ fullmult1.low;
        let fullmult2 = m1.multipliedFullWidth(by: multiplier2)
        let m2 = fullmult2.high ^ fullmult2.low;
        return m2
    }
}
```

It can be used like so:

```
public func randomGen4() {
    let n = 1_000_000
    var sum: UInt64 = 0
    let startTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
    let gen = WyhashGenerator(userSeed: 0)
    for _ in 0..<n {
        sum = sum &+ gen.random() % 10
    }
    let timeElapsed = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - startTime
    print(sum, timeElapsed)
}

do {
    randomGen4()
}
```

---

And here are the benchmark results, with the code compiled in the terminal with optimizations (`-O`) :

```
arc4random_uniform()  : 0.034s
UInt32.random(in:)    : 0.243s
WyHash64              : 0.002s
Xoshiro               : 0.001s
```

---

<sup>You can find more random number generators [here](https://github.com/nvzqz/RandomKit).</sup>

Comment: Please be very thoughtful when switching from `SystemRandomNumberGenerator` to Xoshiro. The former is a cryptographically secure PRNG whenever possible. Xoshiro is not a cryptographically secure PRNG. That's the kind of thing that doesn't matter until it suddenly matters quite a lot. The security of a CSPRNG has a performance cost, so any decent non-CSPRNG should be much faster.

Comment: Note that a RandomNumberGenerator must implement `public mutating func next() -> UInt64` – and then you can call `Int.random(in: 0..<10, using: &x)` instead of modulo arithmetic (which suffers from the “modulo bias” problem).

Comment: Btw, that a RNG compiles without that required method has been observed here: https://forums.swift.org/t/trying-to-use-the-new-randomnumbergenerator-protocol/12919.

Comment: @ielyamani I don't believe Big Crush is a sufficient test for a CSPRNG (cryptographically secure PRNG). Big Crush is just a test of statistical randomness. That's is substantially less than a CSPRNG promises. For example, it is required that it be impractical (i.e. exceeds polynomial time) to determine a CSPRNG's previous outputs, even if you know its full current internal state. Passing basic statistical tests are table stakes in any PRNG, but no statistical test can prove a CSPRNG.

Comment: Wikipedia's CSPRNG article isn't a great intro to the subject IMO, but it does include a nice example of a good PRNG that is completely broken cryptographically. Generate a seed and use it to select a digit of pi. For each iteration, output the next digit. That's perfectly fine for generating a random sequence that will pass statistical tests, but if you know which digit the PRNG is currently computing (i.e. the internal state of the PRNG), it's trivial to determine all the previous digits that were output. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator

Comment: See first comment. It is important that people know whether they're using a secure or insecure PRNG. There's nothing fundamentally wrong with insecure PRNGs. But there are many places that random numbers lead to security issues having nothing to do with encryption. "That's the kind of thing that doesn't matter until it suddenly matters quite a lot." Passing Big Crush has no bearing on the security implications of the choice.

Comment: Never use `CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent`: it's a Wall clock, affected by leap seconds in your calendar. Instead, use a monotonic clock: `mach_absolute_time()`, `ProcessInfo.processInfo.systemUptime`, `DispatchTime.now()` or `CACurrentMediaTime()`.

Comment: @ielyamani I've been aware of that question for nearly 4 years: see nevyn answer and the comments under it. ;)